# Rails: How to explicitly initialize rake tasks "bundled" with a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, sprockets

The `sprockets` gem ships with some `rake` tasks, which are automatically loaded by `rails`.

[The `initialise` method of that task file](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/blob/master/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb#L97) can take an argument (namespace of the tasks, defaults to `assets`), but because it loaded automatically, there is no way to actually give that argument.

What is a clean way to explicitly load these bundled rake tasks in my application, so that I can give the argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no clean way to do this. You can see this by looking at the `sprockets-rails` gem, which initializes sprockets for a rails app. The tasks are added in `lib/sprockets/railtie.rb` in that gem, where L60-61 (in v2.0.1) is:

```
require 'sprockets/rails/task'
Sprockets::Rails::Task.new(app)
```

and if we look at `lib/sprockets/rails/task` we see:

```
class Task < Rake::SprocketsTask
  attr_accessor :app

def initialize(app = nil)
  self.app = app
  super()
end
```

so that's where the `initialize` method you refer to in your question is called when a rails app is initialized. As you can see, no arguments are passed to `super`, so the `SprocketsTask` will be initialized with the default argument. And there's clearly no way for you to pass an argument in without monkey-patching. If this is something you really need, I'd recommend forking `sprockets-rails` and either just using your forked version, or perhaps submit a patch so you can get back on the main branch if it's accepted.